# AppleScript repeat loop gets slower after the first run-through

Tags: applescript, repeat, keystroke

Working on a project rn and trying to figure out why after the first run the whole thing slows down significantly.

keycode 6 using {shift down} is a shortcut to tell another program to execute. Everything works fine when I run the script but the second repeat the whole execution of the program goes so much slower. But if I physically press down the shortcut on my keyboard the execution goes as fast as the first run. 
So I don't know what causes this and I really need this to be stable. What's the best solution. Tried different things, like keystroke (keycode 6 using {shift down}), or keystroke "z" using {shift down} or even

key down shift
key code 6
key up shift

none of which worked...

Here's the code:

```
set filepath to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:main.MurGaa"

tell application "Finder"
open alias filepath
end tell



display dialog "How many profiles do you wanna scrape?" default answer "4000"
set banana to text returned of result
set apple to banana / 50

set progress total steps to apple
set a to 0
set progress completed steps to 0
set progress description to "Scraping..."

repeat apple times

set progress additional description to " profiles scraped: " & (a * 50) & " of " & banana
set progress completed steps to a

tell application "System Events"
    with timeout of 300000 seconds
        key code 6 using {shift down}
        delay 300
    end timeout
end tell

set a to a + 1

end repeat

display dialog "Done! Profiles scraped:" & banana

display dialog "If you want to scrape more profiles just restart the app"

quit
```

Comment: Hello.  May I just commend you on writing a decent, well-formatted and appropriately-detailed question.  Thank you also for including what alternative techniques you tried, what worked and what didn’t.  That’s incredibly helpful. +1

Comment: A couple of questions: how should an average run take, and how long do they actually take when it slows down ? What is the other program that gets executed ?  Could you trigger it another way besides a key press ?  Might the program be responding to the _release_ of a key rather than the pressing of one ?  Lastly, can you detect by some means when the external program has done what it needs to do, rather than using a `delay 300`, which means every loop takes at least 5 minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the positive feedback.

Comment: answer to questions:
the average run takes about 230 s. but for the program work I have to leave some time between for the computer to "rest" before doing another run.
The other program is called "Auto Clicker by Murgaa" and it runs through the macros I programmed within that program.
I could trigger the run by pressing a button within the program but that's really inconvenient because I want the program to constantly run in the backround and the execution should only be seen by the computer doing stuff in the application I want it to run over.
I haven't thought of it might respond to...

Comment: a key release but I'll look in to that asap.
The is no dialog that pops up after the external program has done what it needed to. There is though a function within the program that let's the user repeat the sequence as many times as they want to, but the way I programmed the sequence is to "heavy" for the program to repeat on it's own and it just crashes. That's why I had to do this workaround and it works just fine, except this problem of that the second repeat is waaay slower than the first one.

Comment: And what in particular is actually slower ?  Is it the _Auto Clicker_ that runs slower, such as it takes longer to move the mouse to where it's supposed to be and issue a mouse click ?  Or is it the length of time between the keypress and when _Auto Clicker_ responds ?  Or something else ?

Comment: the Auto Clicker runs slower. And I do now know why. Because when I press the shortcut the normal speed is achieved whether or not the script is running or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some trial and error I figured out that it was the other program that I triggered that was getting slowed down because the window was not active. So in the settings of Auto Clicker there was this function to always be in front. I checked that one and now everything works smooth. The script also.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I didn't help at all, sadly.  But it was clearly a problem no one was going to solve without access to the application and set up.  Glad you got it sorted.  You can mark your own answer as the accepted answer, seeing as it has solved the issue.